# Linux Find file with negation in Bash Script

Tags: find

In my linux folder there are following files：

```
abc.txt
test.log
kkk.war
Type1_20160814.xml
Type1_20160624.xml
Type1_20160703.xml
Type1_20160503.xml
```

I want to gzip Type1 files that **NOT** belongs to current month, which is August (i can't use mtime).

Expected Result, the following files gzip-ed:

```
Type1_20160624.xml
Type1_20160703.xml
Type1_20160503.xml
```

Actually i tried:

```
files=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -type f -name "Type1_201608*.xml")
gzip -5 ${files[@]}
```

BUT, it also gzip files that not Type1（like following）, how can i avoid that？

```
abc.txt
test.log
kkk.war
```

Comment: `-type f -name "Type1_*xml" -not -name '*_201608*'`

Comment: `find * -prune -type f -name "Type1_*xml" -not -name '*_201608*' -exec gzip -5 {} +`

Comment: @Costas why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @F.Hauri Wait for OP responce if that what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -type f -name "Type1_201608*.xml"
> ```

This means: for the files in the current directory (`. -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1`), list the files that are not regular files (`-not -type f`), and that have a name matching `"Type1_201608*.xml`.

Since you want to list only files that match `Type1_*.xml`, your command is going to have to include this pattern somehere! And since you want to act on regular files, don't negate `-type f`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "Type1_*.xml" ! -name "Type1_201608*.xml"
```

[Don't parse the output of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). Use `-exec`, that's what it's for.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "Type1_*.xml" ! -name "Type1_201608*.xml" -exec gzip -5 {} +
```

With modern shells, if the pattern `Type1_*.xml` doesn't match any directory or any symbolic link that you want to exclude, you don't need `find` for this. You can use ksh extended glob patterns, which are [also available in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching).

```
shopt -s extglob
gzip -5 Type1_!(201608*).xml
```

In zsh, you can enable ksh extended glob patterns, but you can also use [zsh's own](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators).

```
setopt extended_glob
gzip -5 Type1_*.xml~Type1_201608*
```

Or

```
gzip -5 Type1_(^201608*).xml
```

And in zsh, if you want to ensure that only regular files are matched, you can use a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
setopt extended_glob
gzip -5 Type1_(^201608*).xml(.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` with the `extglob` shell option set:

```
$ shopt -s extglob

$ echo Type1_????!(08)??.xml
Type1_20160503.xml Type1_20160624.xml Type1_20160703.xml

$ gzip Type1_????!(08)??.xml
```

The `!(something)` pattern will match anything *except* `something`.

This also works in `ksh` (where that syntax comes from) *without* setting any non-default option.

Answer (score 0):

I tried executing below command in the working directory and all the files got gziped.

to execute in same directory

> gzip -f $(ls -l | grep Type1 | grep -v $(date +%Y%m) | awk '{print $NF}')

to execute from different directory in ls we need to add the folder name as argument

> gzip -5 $(ls -lrt -d -1 test/* | grep Type1 | grep -v $(date +%Y%m) | awk '{print $NF}')

#### Recieved output

Type1_20160102.xml.gz

Type1_20160105.xml.gz

Type1_20160624.xml.gz

Type1_20160703.xml.gz

Type1_20160704.xml.gz

Type1_20160705.xml.gz

> this command's will zip all the files in directory name Type1 excluding  current month files